# Define a variable to True in header file that i later changed in cpp

Tags: c++, qt

What is the best way for me to define a variable called

```
bool isLeftSidebarVisible = true;
```

in the header file which i then want to change from the cpp file?

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:    
    MainWindow(QString filePath);
    ~MainWindow();

    bool isDirty() const;
    bool isLeftSidebarVisible();
...
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QString filePath)
    :d_ptr(new MainWindowPrivate)
{
    d_ptr->defaultTitle = tr("My Application") + tr(_APP_VERSION_);
    setCurrentFileName(filePath);
    setWindowTitle(d_ptr->defaultTitle);
    ...
```

I'm not entirely sure how to access the variable from the cpp file to change it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a `isLeftSidebarVisible()` member function in the class to do the "getting", so it'll make sense for you to have a setter member function `setLeftSidebarVisible(bool)` to modify it.

You'll place the boolean member variable declaration in the private section of the `MainWindow` class to make it a class member variable which is then accessible from any `MainWindow` class function.

But don't have the variable with the exact same spelling as the getter function else there'll probably be name lookup ambiguities.